# PHP: mysql_query INSERT INTO grab id?

Tags: php, mysql

so i have this:   mysql_query("INSERT INTO..."); I was wondering after you've inserted if you could echo out the id of the column you have inserted, or should i SELECT and that all around again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this function: mysql_insert_id() - Gets the ID generated in the last query

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')");
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
```

More info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)